# select between two date attributes with predefined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the records between two date attributes in mysql, but the query I am trying doesnt work, maybe because the date attribute is not a string so it cant compare it!

This is the query that I tried.

```
SELECT * 
FROM object, object_info
WHERE oi_object = o_id
AND o_category =  '6'
AND o_address =  'Gostivar'
AND o_status =  'approved'
AND o_available_from >= date(2013-08-15)
AND o_available_to <= date(2013-08-31)
ORDER BY o_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the date values in single quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM object, object_info
WHERE oi_object = o_id
AND o_category =  '6'
AND o_address =  'Gostivar'
AND o_status =  'approved'
AND o_available_from >= date('2013-08-15')
AND o_available_to <= date('2013-08-31')
ORDER BY o_date DESC ;
```

Your query was actually doing:

```
AND o_available_from >= date(2013 - 08 - 15)
AND o_available_to <= date(2013 - 08 - 31)
```

which is

```
AND o_available_from >= date(1980)
AND o_available_to <= date(1974)
```

And I don't think you really want that.

Comment: Thank you this did the trick but why do you think that I dont want this, will it cause a problem?

Comment: @TooCooL . . . I don't think you want to do the integer arithmetic before applying `date()`.  I think you want the string constant.